# Google forms appscript email sends only one form value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I tried creating an appscript to send an email.

Form Url: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1kpH01RQRshKw_CEAgs9aM8AjNyrvBKDhJYC856BwO6M/edit?pli=1#settings

Appscript i'm trying as below

```
function onSubmit(e){
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var reporter = e.response.getRespondentEmail();

  var message = '';
  for (var i =0; i<=items.length;i++) {
    var items = items[i];
    var question = items.getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = items.getResponse();
    message += (i + 1).toString() + '. ' + question + ': ' + answer + '\n';
}
 FormApp.getActiveForm();

  var email = "sohamtracysdsf2289@email.com"; // it is working untill here and can send email
  var title = 'Event RSP';
  var content = 'This is a RSVP Request\n\n' + message;
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, title, content,{cc:reporter});


}
```

However, my email is triggering only 1 result[image]

I need all the options in the form to be sent in email.  Could you help me on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not iterating inside all the questions inside the form, I created a simplified sample, you can test it out and apply the changes to your code or use the sample.

I created the code based on the [Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) and the [Class GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body).

Here is the code:

```
function rsvp_sender() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();

  // Target the last submission of the Google Form
  var i = formResponses.length-1;

  var formResponse = formResponses[i];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  //Empty list to add all the iterations of all the questions
  // inside the form. 
  let questions = [];

    // Starts a for loop to get all the questions 
    // and responses in the loop and their answers. 
    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
      var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
      
      // Add the information of the questions 
      // and responses to the empty list.
      questions += (i + 1).toString() + '. The answer to the question "' 
      + itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() + '" was "' + itemResponse.getResponse() 
      + '"\n'
    }

    // completes the body of the email 
  content =  'This is a RSVP Request\n\n'+ questions
  GmailApp.sendEmail('user@domain.xyz','Event RSP', content);
}
```

And the email looks like this:

[image]

For this case, I [manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) added the trigger, Like this:

[image]

I tested filling out the form with multiple users (inside of workspace and Gmail.com,) and the email was sent without issues. Even if the other users didn’t have the trigger installed.

---

**Update to hide the Responses Number (The 16):**

To remove the number for `16. The answer to the question...` you need to change:

```
 questions += (i + 1).toString() + '. The answer to the question "' 
      + itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() + '" was "' + itemResponse.getResponse() 
      + '"\n'
```

for:

```
 questions += 'The answer to the question "' 
      + itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() + '" was "' + itemResponse.getResponse() 
      + '"\n'
```

---

**Update to number the questions:**

Replace:

```
questions += (i + 1).toString() + '. The answer to the question "' 
      + itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() + '" was "' + itemResponse.getResponse() 
      + '"\n'
```

for:

```
questions += (j + 1).toString() + '. The answer to the question "' 
      + itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() + '" was "' + itemResponse.getResponse() 
      + '"\n'
```

Comment: Thanks @Giselle Valladares. Quick question, I see there is a number generating in the output. Example, in your screenshot, it has 16. Is there anyway, I can showit in order (1,2,3,4...)  or hide it?

Comment: Yes, you can replace: `questions += (i + 1).toString() + '. The answer to the question "' 
      + itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() + '" was "' + itemResponse.getResponse() 
      + '"\n'` for `questions +=  'The answer to the question "' 
      + itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() + '" was "' + itemResponse.getResponse() 
      + '"\n'`. Let me add an update.

Comment: @Tony, I updated the answer to answer your last question.